# Fadein Fadeout Effects in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am using jquery addClass and removeClass function

here is code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    abc();

    function abc() {

        res=randomXToY(1,15,0);
            $('#img' + res).addClass('activeImg');
            setTimeout(function() {removeClassImg(res) },3000);
    }
    function removeClassImg(res) {

            $('#img' + res).removeClass('activeImg');
            abc();

    }
    function randomXToY(minVal,maxVal,floatVal)
    {
        var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
        return typeof floatVal=='undefined'?Math.round(randVal):randVal.toFixed(floatVal);
    }
});
</script>
```

and css is

```
.activeImg{
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

This is working perfect. but now i want to add fadein and Fadeout effects for this..

I dont have idea how to add Fadein effect to addClass activeimg and fadeout effect in remove class.

Anybody have idea about this

Thanks

Comment: First you should remove `!important` from CSS.

Comment: this is not answer of my question

Comment: Sure, this is a comment.

Comment: why to remove !important give reasons

Comment: Epic! +1 since it made my day right at the beginning! =DD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#img' + res).fadeOut().removeClass('activeImg');
```

and similarly

```
$('#img' + res).fadeIn().addClass('activeImg');
```

Is there any specific reason you're using !important? That might override the JQuery from perfoming its effects to your element, so take it off if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
abc();

function abc() {

    res=randomXToY(1,15,0);
        $('#img' + res).fadeIn().addClass('activeImg');
        setTimeout(function() {removeClassImg(res) },3000);
}
function removeClassImg(res) {

        $('#img' + res).fadeOut().removeClass('activeImg');
        abc();

}
function randomXToY(minVal,maxVal,floatVal)
{
    var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
    return typeof floatVal=='undefined'?Math.round(randVal):randVal.toFixed(floatVal);
}
   });
  </script>
```

Cheers !